# robot framework, expected 0 arguments got 2

Tags: csv, robotframework

I have the following code:

```
Original Crear Variable Experto
[Documentation]
Consultar RUT existente
[Arguments] ${argumentorut}     
[Tags]    PersonalInformation()      
${var_object}=      Create Wsdl Object              ${SERVICE_NAME}               En Experto Original es ns0:VARInput

Set Wsdl Object Attribute          ${var_object}          rut          ${argumentorut}

    Set Soap Headers                  ${var_object}            
    Set Location                      ${SECURE WS URL}
    [Return]       ${var_object}
```

And I'm instantiating it

```
WS Experto Original Consulta y Respuesta
[Documentation]      Envía consulta válida a WS Experto Original y obtiene respuesta
[Arguments]          ${param_rutsindf}

Run Keyword If       ${SET_LOGGING}       Log        ${URL_ORIG}

Create Soap Client   ${URL_ORIG}

Se crean las variables usando los valores almacenados en listas.
${var_RUT}=         Original Crear Variable Experto    ${RUT_EXISTE1}    ${param_rutsindf}


${list}= Create List   ${var_RUT}



${obj}=         Create Wsdl Object          ${SERVICE_NAME}            # En Experto Original es ns0:SRUTInput
Set Wsdl Object Attribute       ${obj}         rut                  ${list}


Set Location         ${URL_ORIG}

Retorna un string ASCII soap.
${RESULT}=       Call Soap Method        personalInformation     ${list}      METODO DEL WEB SERVICE 
Set Global Variable        ${RESULT}
[Return]
```

My error:

```
Keyword 'Resourse.Original Crear Variable Experto' expected 0 arguments, got 2
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have two or more spaces after `[Arguments]` in the definition of `Original Crear Variable Experto`. Therefore, robot doesn't think that keyword accepts any arguments.

Change this:

```
[Arguments] ${argumentorut}
```

To this:

```
[Arguments]  ${argumentorut}
```

If you fix that, you appear to have another problem. You are calling the keyword with two arguments, but the keyword accepts only one. I don't know if the bug is that you're sending too many, or that you're expecting too few.